# Prime numbers in polygonal integer systems

Tags: number-theory, complex-numbers, prime-numbers

In the Gaussian Integers, a Classical prime is only Gaussian prime if it is 3 mod 4 and is Gaussian composite if it is 1 mod 4 (or 2 mod 4, but that only happens once).

In the Eisenstein Integers, a Classical prime is only Eisenstein prime if it is 5 mod 6 (or 2 mod 6, but that only happens once), and is Eisenstein composite if it is 1 mod 6 (or 3 mod 6, but that also only happens once).

However, this pattern runs across a problem in other polygonal integer systems*: 2, 3, 4, and 6 are the only mods that force general primes to be 1 or n-1 mod n.

So the question is which is the General Rule:

> The only Classical primes that are n-gonal prime are of the form n-1 mod n, with the possible exception of certain factors of n

or

> The only Classical primes that aren't n-gonal prime are of the form 1 mod n, with the possible exception of certain factors of n

Considering the Classical Integers, it seems the first rule is the general rule, as the fact that 1 mod 2 is n-1 mod n appears to override the fact that it is also 1 mod n, but this observation is hardly a proof. I am also open to the idea that the split might actually be somewhere between 1 and n-1

---

*a "polygonal integer system" is my name for a certain generalization of Gaussian, Eisenstein and Classical Integers: The "n" of "n-gonal" corresponds to the n nth-roots of unity, which then trace out an n-gon of radius 1 around the origin. Under this naming scheme, Classical Integers are digonal, Gaussian Integers are tetragonal, and Eisenstein Integers are hexagonal (hence my use of mod 6, rather than the more common mod 3, in my definition of Eisenstein Integers). If a name for this generalization already exists, please share it with me, and I will edit my post accordingly.

Comment: I'm not sure what your background is, but if you know some Galois theory and want to dive into some algebraic number theory, you could search the phrase "factorization of primes in cyclotomic extensions", which is the answer to your question. In general, a classical prime $p$ remains an "$n$-gonal prime" if and only if $p$ mod $n$ is a generator of the group $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^\times$.

Comment: I don't know much Galois theory, but there's always a time to start learning. Thanks for the keywords.

Comment: No problem! Unfortunately you won't be able to prove the statement that I wrote above, but hopefully you can still appreciate it! One corollary is that there are no classical primes that are also "$8$-gonal primes": Because $(\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z})^\times \cong (\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^2$ isn't cyclic, no prime can generate the whole thing.